# Trying to print using a cordova plugin for zebra printers in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, zebra-printers

We are currently developing an ionic 4 application for android devices in which we are required to print receipts using a zebra printer. Unfortunately, we are not able to get it to work.

We have found a plugin called 'ca-cleversolutions-zebraprinter' which seems to support our use case. But we are getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:71
    at Module../node_modules/ca-cleversolutions-zebraprinter/native/index.js (index.js:118)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
   at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
```

With some research we have found that this issue is only thrown when the plugin is used in an ionic 4 application and not in ionic 3 because the plugin template for ionic 4 is different than that of ionic 3.

Here is our code:

Home.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Zebra Printer
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-button color="primary"  (click) = "connectPrint()">click here to Connect Zebra Printer Device</ion-button>
  <ion-button color="primary"  (click) = "printReceipt()">click here to Print</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Home.page.ts:

```
import { ZebraPrinter } from 'ca-cleversolutions-zebraprinter/native';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  providers:[ZebraPrinter]
})
export class HomePage {
  data :string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
  constructor(protected zebraPrinter:ZebraPrinter) {}

  /*
    Zebra Printer options
  */
connectPrint(){
    console.log("Discover the Zebra device");
    this.zebraPrinter.discover().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ZebraPrinter } from 'ca-cleversolutions-zebraprinter/native';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ZebraPrinter,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Is there a way where we could get this plugin to work in ionic 4? Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ionic but have used [this plugin](https://github.com/prakashsatyani/cordova-plugin-ble-zbtprinter) in cordova.

`discover()` function does not seem to work here. You need to pair the zebra printer beforehand. I did following things:

1) Ask for location permission from the user on the first time app startup ([plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#haspermission)). After that ask the user to also enable GPS from the GPS settings ([plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#requestlocation)).

2) After that on click of your "**Print**" button, initialize and enable Bluetooth ([plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#enable))

3) You will need to search for paired devices for the printer and it's MAC address. Use [this plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#list) to get the list of paired devices and search for a device that has name something like XXxxxxxxxxxx.

4) After getting the printer's MAC address, use `print()` method of the plugin to print your ZPL labels.